# mssql select GETDATE - all day from 00:00 - 23:59

Tags: sql, sql-server

Running MS SQL Server 2008

I have this query:

```
select count(*) from dbo.study
where study_datetime >= (GETDATE() -1)
```

that comes back with all of yesterdays exams written to my study table.  How would I make it come back with everything done 'today' up to the current time I asked for it?  For example I would everything for today from 00:00:00.000 - current time

my values in the 'study_datetime' column look like:  2014-05-06 10:40:31.000

I can't seem to figure this one out.  I have tried replacing the '-1' with a '0' but I get back 0 results.

thanks

Comment: I like this idea, but how would I use the 'getdate' function with a time of 00:00:00.000 and another with 23:59:59.000?

Comment: So, you want to exclude anything that happened at, say, `23:59:59.237`? That's why, as I said, it's almost always better to get "midnight tomorrow" and use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: No, I don't.  I want to see everything from 00:00:00.000 to 23:59:59.000.  Sorry, I misunderstood

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get everything that strictly happened today, just use:

```
select count(*) from dbo.study
where study_datetime >= cast(getDate() As Date)
and study_datetime < cast(DATEADD(day,1,getdate()) as Date)
```

When you're working with continuous data, it's almost always better to switch to using semi-open intervals, to ensure that data falls into one and exactly one interval. Usually, when you want "all day", you don't want to exclude things that occurred during the final minute of the day (at e.g. 23:59:37.223 or even at 23:59:59.993). So you'd normally write your query to be `>= midnight at the start of the day` and `< midnight at the start of the following day` (note the different types of comparisons)

This is usually a far better idea than trying to compute the last moment of today and use `<=` (or `BETWEEN`) for your comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately there is no trunc() like in oracle, but since you have the 2008 version you can use:

`select count(*) from dbo.study
where study_datetime >= cast(getDate() As Date)`

Comment: this looks good, but it displays everything from today and in the future.  Unfortunately, random machines dates had been set to a future date probably due to a bad CMOS battery, so there study_datetimes that extend past 2014.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well (values from same day), I think you can use DATEDIFF function, using the day as datepart.

```
select count(*) from dbo.study
where datediff(dd, study_datetime, GETDATE()) = 0
and study_datetime  <= GETDATE() -- if you need a check for the "future" (datetime after GETDATE() )
```

Answer (score 0):

select count(*) from dbo.study
where study_datetime between :2014-05-06 00:00:00 and :2014-05-06 23:59:59.

It might help you